# comparing two columns within same dataframe and computing statistics from comparison

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe that has datetime as index and 3 columns, id, revenue and cost.

```
d = {'id' : ['4573', '4573', '4573', '958245','958245','958245'] \
,'revenue' : np.random.uniform(size=6),'cost' : np.random.uniform(size=6)}
e = ['2014-03-01','2014-04-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2015-03-01','2015-02-01']

dateindex = [datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d') for a in e]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.index = dateindex

    cost    id  revenue
2014-03-01  0.445597    4573    0.901713
2014-04-01  0.774029    4573    0.908302
2014-05-01  0.104274    4573    0.278444
2014-05-01  0.938426    958245  0.755022
2015-03-01  0.647886    958245  0.125072
2015-02-01  0.267773    958245  0.557496
```

I want to perform various comparisons between revenue and cost for each id.

For example:

Pseudocode:

```
If Revenue > Cost > 0
 CountA = CountA + 1
Elif 0 < Revenue < Cost 
 CountB = CountB + 1
Elif Revenue > 0 > Cost
 CountC = CountC + 1
Elif Revenue = 0 and Cost > 0
 CountD = CountD + 1
```

For case A I thought I could do:

```
df[['revenue']][df['id'] == '4573'] > df[['cost']][df['id'] == '4573']
```

But I got:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Is there a more efficient way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create the function you want, then build it in a way it could be applied upon a df, then groupby 'id' and apply the function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import collections

d = {'id' : ['4573', '4573', '4573', '958245','958245','958245'] \
 ,'revenue' : np.random.uniform(size=6),'cost' : np.random.uniform(size=6)}
e = ['2014-03-01','2014-04-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2015-03-01','2015-02-01']

dateindex = [datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d') for a in e]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.index = dateindex

#create basic function
def Func(Cost,Revenue):
    if Revenue > Cost > 0:
        return 'A'
    elif  Cost>Revenue>0 :
        return 'B'
    elif Revenue > 0 > Cost:
        return 'C'
    elif Revenue == 0 and Cost > 0:
        return 'D'

#create a function to use on df
def Func_df(df):
    cases_list =  [Func(x,y) for x,y in zip(df.cost.values,df.revenue.values)]
    return collections.Counter(cases_list)

df.groupby('id').apply(Func_df)
```

Output (hopefully):

```
id
4573      {u'A': 1, u'B': 2}
958245    {u'A': 1, u'B': 2}
```